# Android SQLite input duplicates

Tags: android, sqlite, validation, duplicates

I'm working on an SQLite Android app. I want to get rid of any duplicates while inserting data to the table.
My code:

> **Method from DatabaseHelper class (RCOL_2 is String):**

```
public Cursor getResourceName(String condition) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + RCOL_2 + " FROM " + RESOURCE_TABLE + " WHERE " + RCOL_2 + " = " + "'" + condition + "'", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

> **MainActivity:**

```
public boolean checkResourceDuplicates(String insert) {
    Cursor result = databaseHelper.getResourceName(insert);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    ArrayList<StringBuffer> values = new ArrayList<>();

    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        buffer.append(result.getString(0));
    }
    values.add(buffer);

    for (int i=0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if(values.get(i).toString().equals(insert)){
            return true;
        }
    }return false;
}



public void addResource() {
    btnAddResource.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if(checkResourceDuplicates(editResourceName.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Duplicate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    boolean isInserted = databaseHelper.insertResource(editResourceName.getText().toString(), addCategoryID(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                    if (isInserted == true) {
                        editResourceName.setText(null);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Resource added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Resource not added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

For now, it allows to add to the database for example: 'a' and 'A'.
I tried with equalsIgnoreCase method, selecting lower from the database... and nothing. In the best case I managed to prevent adding '`AaAa`' after adding '`aaaa`', but adding '`aaaa`' after '`AaAa`' was allowed.

I tried SELECT LOWER(column_name), adding it to array list, converting insert value to lowerCase and matching these. Didn't work. I don't want to make additional trash table in my database to validate this.

Answer (score 1):

if i follow your question.. you need to convert your text to lowercase then insert it into a separate column >> apply unique attribute on it.. and insert with `insertWithOnConflict`.. something like that.

while creating table..

```
KEY_NAME+" TEXT UNIQUE"
```

and insert data as.

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way without creating additional table?

Comment: no need to create a additional table.. just add a column in `RESOURCE_TABLE`. that will hold the lowercase text of your origenal text. in this way you can apply unique on the particular table.

Comment: So why SELECT LOWER(column_name), adding it to array list, converting insert value to lowerCase and matching these doesn't work? It makes absolutely no sense to me...